# PHP : Return remote image url src with width and height where width greater than 500px

Tags: php, curl, getimagesize

So far I've successfully returned all img > src attributes from the remote url however if I want to get the width and height of these it takes ages to check them all not to mention on top of this load time I check each url returns a status 200 just incase.

Effectively I'm looking for a solution that returns 5 images which are over 500px < 1000px in size from a remote url without having to download the entire file to check its size.

Answer (score 0):

That is not actually possible since that data is embedded in the image. It's not some sort of header you can just grab. In order to do what you want, you ***need*** to download the entire image to get its width and height unfortunately.

Comment: There are components out there which text-stream the remote line by line until the right data is reached.